# While creating a site collection in SharePoint 2016 , getting error

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, error, site-collection, feature

Whenever I am trying to create a site collection in SharePoint 2016 , I am getting below error.

> "Error while creating the workspace. Please contact your user
>   helpdesk.Feature definition with Id
>   da9840a0-18e6-4804-abe9-c3e0b6b0a451 failed validation, file
>   'ElementsContentType.xml', line 1, character 22130: The 'Hidden'
>   attribute is invalid - The value '$Resources:core,True_Unless_Jpn;' is
>   invalid according to its datatype
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/:TRUEFALSEorResource' - The
>   Enumeration constraint failed."

I tried to get the feature using feature  id but it is showing

> "Cannot find a Feature object with Path or Id:
>   da9840a0-18e6-4804-abe9-c3e0b6b0a451 in scope Local farm."

Comment: Do you try to use a custom site template?

Comment: Yes . I used custom template to create site collection .